# ¿ Como puedo saber cuantas letras tiene una palabra en IONIC TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, ionic, funciones

Hola y gracias de antemano por su colaboración, Mientras trabajaba en un frontend basado en ionic me he visto en la necesidad de contar los caracteres de una palabra, el código que utilizo es el siguiente:

**component.html:**

```
<ion-input type="password" placeholder="Escriba aqui" (change)=checkStrenght(actualPass) [(ngModel)]="actualPass"></ion-input>
```

**component.ts:**

```
 checkStrenght(actualPass) {
    console.log(actualPass)
  }
```

Objetivo: en vez de mostrar por consola "actualPass" (devuelve lo que se escribe en mi input) quiero que devuelva el número de caracteres de los que se compone.

Ejemplo: Si actualPass es igual a "pass123" la función devuelve devuelve 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La propiedad length de un objeto String representa la longitud de una cadena, en unidades de código UTF-16.

```
checkStrenght(actualPass) {
        console.log(actualPass.length)
      }
```

Comment: me funciona muchisimas gracias,